# Сайт не ищется в гугл, но в яндексе ищется

Tags: google-chrome, seo, hosting, google-search

Установили *ssl-сертификат* часов 12 назад, в Яндексе сайт хорошо находится, а в гугле его вообще не найти, только через адрес...

В чем может быть проблема, почти не разбираюсь в SEO.

В robots.txt написано:

```
user-agent: yandex
Disallow: "какой-то адрес %D0%... "
```

Вдруг это как-то связано.

Адрес сайта profligastroi.ru (https и http, www и без www)

Comment: Зарегистрируйтесь в google webmaster tools, вбейте там свой сайт, дождитесь индексации

Comment: Сделал так, долго индексация происходит?

Comment: Сайт и так проиндексирован гуглом, раз "через адрес" находится. А когда, где, и по каким запросам и появится в выдаче (если появится) - это решит сам гугл.